# Space after comma in units package

Tags: math-mode, spacing, units

I have a problem with using the `units` package. In my thesis I used it sometimes in math environment, sometimes not. Now I realized that there is an addition space after the comma in math mode. I think this is a problem of European and American writing of decimal comma and decimal point.

Can you tell me, how I can delete the space after the comma in the math environment?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{units}

\begin{document}

$V=\unit[0,5]{V}$
\unit[0,5]{V}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Noone uses unit anymore, switch to siunitx, it can be configured to use comma in the proper manner. Besides in some countries, even if comma is the standard decimal sign, it may still be legal to use the dot in scientific context

Comment: Well, so I'm nobody... It's an very large document and it would take a lot of time to switch everything from units to siunitx. Is there any faster way instead of replacing everything?

Comment: @daleif I wish CTAN would indicate deprecations...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `units`, use the [`icomma`](http://ctan.org/pkg/icomma) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{units,icomma}
\begin{document}
$V=\unit[0,5]{V}$
\unit[0,5]{V}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

As daleif says, use the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  locale = DE % Gives comma as decimal separator.
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$V = \SI{0.5}{\V}$

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

Reading your comments, you would like to keep your `\unit` command working. Lucky for you, LaTeX allows you to redefine command. Because `\unit` should behave as `\SI` when an optional argument is given and as `\si` when only a unit is given, some trickery is involved.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\let\unit\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\unit}[2][]{
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     \si{#2}
   \else
     \SI{#1}{#2}
   \fi}

\begin{document}   
$V=\unit[0,5]{V}$
\unit[0,5]{V} 
\end{document}
```

We first let the old `\unit`do nothing. Then we redefine it as to behave like `\si` when the optional argument is empty, or as `\SI` when it is not.

Comment: With `xparse` it's even easier: `\NewDocumentCommand{\unit}{om}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\si{#2}}{\SI{#1}{#2}}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `units`, then you can surround the comma with curly braces in math mode:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{units}

\begin{document}

$V=\unit[0{,}5]{V}$
\unit[0,5]{V}

\end{document}
```