# Comma in math mode

Tags: punctuation

In some countries one use comma as decimal separator instead of a dot.

I ususally use:

```
%%%% Une vrai virgule pour les décimaux
\DeclareMathSymbol{@}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
```

and `$3@2$` to obtain 3,2
instead of `$3,2$` that gives 3, 2 <- a uggly useless space after comma

I just find this :

```
\mathcode`\.="8000
{\catcode`\.=\active
\gdef.{,}}
```

That replaces automatically a dot by a comma in math mode, but with the ungly useless space.

Is there a way to combine both technics to have an automatic sustitution with a proper comma ?

**Edit** Sorry !

It was obvious :

```
%%%% Une vrai virgule pour les décimaux
\DeclareMathSymbol{@}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
\mathcode`\.="8000
{\catcode`\.=\active
\gdef.{@}}
```

Could this code have boder effect ?
Is there a better or other way to get this ?

Comment: Try to use the `siunitx` package. Here you can define your decimal-seperator (Denmark uses comma here as well) and use \num{3,2} in order to express your values. Note that the package can do alot more, check out the docs.

Comment: Does \num{3,2} change depending of the country you are? Is the result will be right for a Danish and for an English, each in his country ? I look for some thing automatic you put in your .sty that some one esle coud change and cherry on the cake with no special syntax.

Comment: The localisation options for `siunitx` are set in the document preamble, and thus can be changed in one place. Alternately, you could move them to a `.sty` file.

Comment: That I understand. Once you typeset \num{3,2} as a Danish or a French, you'll see 3,2. How can an English see 3.2? Not from the pdf of course, but if I give him the .tex source.

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154916/space-after-comma-in-units-package

Comment: Try `\gdef.{{,}}` instead of `\gdef.{,}` to get rid of the extra space.

Comment: There is a package `icomma`, improving the math spacings for comma.

Comment: @HenriMenke But I steal it from you ;-)

Comment: There's nor real "full" solution, for the simple reason that in some cases you want the comma to be ordinary (numbers) and in other cases (ordered pairs, for instance) to be punctuation. The `icomma` package does its best by checking what's next, but needs some help in certain cases. The best is to use `\num`.

Comment: AFAIK the only use of . is decimal separator, otherwise one uses \dots and so ever. In fact one could always use . as decimal separator in mathmode, and if one wants he should add the automatic substitution code in is preambule or .sty. Did I say something wrong ? ;-)

Comment: One might as well say that *some* countries use a dot instead of a comma as decimal separator… ;)

Comment: @HenriMenke There is a huge and amazing side effect with your 3 lines: \input{./file} gives ! LaTeX Error: File `,/file.tex' not found.

Comment: @Tarass Changing catcodes will **ALWAYS** have its downsides. Better use @DavidCarlisle's solution ``\mathcode`\.=\mathcode`\,``.

Comment: @HenriMenke sounds better ;-) thank you.

Comment: In addition to @Argo's comment, let me know that in Danish typography it is legal to use do as the decimal point in scientific contexts. That is what we recommend our users to do, because retrofitting a 50 pages thesis with `\num` etc takes a very long time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your original question. You could redefine `.` to produce another symbol in math mode.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
```

Here in a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\mathchardef\period=\mathcode`.
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
\begin{document}
$3.2$
$3\period2$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Yes, it's easier than using @ and because the only use of . in mathmode is decimal separator.

Comment: ``\mathchardef\period=\mathcode`.`` before `\DeclareMathSymbol{.}` is better, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg Nifty, thank you `:-)` I added this to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is more simple syntax which working only in mathmode:

```
\mathcode`,="002C
```