# PGF pretty number printing equivalent in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, parsing

For TikZ and `pgfplots` I use :

```
\tikzset{/pgf/number format/.cd,use comma,1000 sep={\,}}
```

And all numbers are typeset accordingly, with no other command.

Is there a way to have the same convenience for a LaTeX document?

Not using any command such as `\nombre{}` nor `\num{}` but in something like for the math mode comma : [Comma in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173729/comma-in-math-mode)

Comment: Short answer here is going to be 'no', at least not 'safely'. Remember that while you only see the number of `pgfplots`, internally it can wrap it up in a formatting command (based on `\pgfmathparse` here).

Comment: LaTeX doesn't format your number automatically anyway. So you need to use an external mechanism to parse your number. That can be `\num`,`\pgfmathprintnumber` etc.